# I want to draw custom shape like apple shape on UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, draw

I am trying to make Apple kind of shape for progressHUD. I have option to use .png Image but I cant because I have to fill the apple Shape with different colour depends of percentage status.. I am using **UIView** to **draw** this shape...

- I want suggestion how to draw apple kind of shape easily?
- And How we can fill half colour with different colour?

Comment: See this code on github. I have done my task my self using below code... .

Comment: https://github.com/BevinPatel/BKProgressHUD

Answer (score 5):

> I have option to use .png Image but I cant

Yes, you can. — Get hold of some apple-shaped artwork. Use it as a *mask* - it punches a hole in a view. Now put another view behind it, with a color. Now the apple appears to be that color, because that color is being seen through the apple-shaped hole. Now put *another* view behind it, with a different color, and move it up or across the right amount so as to divide what's seen through the apple into *two* colors.

Using that approach, it took me about 30 seconds to create this result (using *your* apple-shaped artwork as a *.png* image!):

[image]

Comment: No, I'm not going to write the code for you. You asked for an approach; I described an approach (and showed you the result). Use it or don't, but you have to do the actual work.

Comment: Hey Matt see the liabrery. thanks so much for your guidence I have done my Task.. and Its on github... 
https://github.com/BevinPatel/BKProgressHUD