# How can I make an animation in stars? Swift

Tags: swift

Here is my problem: I developed an App that split fairly teams for a soccer game. It also can count the goals of each player. The player that makes a goal has his level up. I want an animation that shows the star been filled. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the way you want your animation to look like.

My suggestion is to make a empty star (just a border) and make it full size. Then add another on top of it (thats filled).

Before the animation starts you need to resize that star so it's nonexistent (width and height are zero)

```
filledStar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)
```

and then animate it to full size like this

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
    filledStar.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
}
```

You can also play around with spring animations so it over extends and then goes to full size, but that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the star shape as a mask and animate the movement of a colored view behind it, as I suggest in this answer (where what is being filled is an apple, not a star, but it is the same technique):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29553645/341994

[image]