ImageView with percentage fill color clockwise
Hello I wanted to achieve something like this using UIKit

But the only thing I could do it was this

Someone has any idea on how to achieve this, I tried with bezierPath and maskLayer, but I couldn't fill the remain part with another color, because the tintColor can not have multiple colors

Will you always have a black background? Do you want to animate the percentage change?

Possible duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29553645/341994

Yeah I just need practically the tintColor to have the percentage change, animation is a plus

I believe you're on the right track!
All you need is to have TWO UIImageViews, one on top of another.
Set the darker image to the one that is behind (or decrease the opacity, or set a tint color.. up to you).
Set the normal one to the one that is on top. Play with the .path property of the masked layer (just like in your screenshot) and you should get the desired result.

Holy cow, that's a good idea, I will try it :)
